# How to find out if the memory belongs to heap or stack?

Tags: c++, c, memory

As I am finding out the  memory address of a variable using a debugger,
I get something like 0x602010 or 0x7fffffffe0d8.

One belongs to heap memory and the other one belongs to stack memory.

The first one is a memory address from heap and the latter one is from stack memory.
I know this since the first one is an address from malloc() and the second one is the memory address of a local variable.

I am curious to find out if there is a way to know if a certain address belongs to stack or heap just from looking at their memory addresses.

Comment: Compile it wit a map file generation and look in it.

Comment: malloc allocations are heap memory

Comment: Without further knowledge of the compiler and environment, no. Nothing in the language standard will solve this for you. There isn't even a strict guarantee that malloc() will always allocate from the heap afaik.

Comment: _"I know this since the first one is an address from malloc() and the second one is the memory address of a local variable."_ Woah there hang on. Does not compute. You have no guarantees then that _"One belongs to heap memory and the other one belongs to stack memory."_ it's just a wild assumption. It would really be better to avoid this requirement in the first place. Why do you think you need to know this? C++ is an abstraction; code within the abstraction and you'll be fine.

Comment: @SeekAddo: _"malloc allocations are heap memory"_ That is a gross oversimplification and is not always true. This whole "stack vs heap" thing needs to die!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - If malloc() doesn't allocate from heap, where does it allocate from?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's some implementation detail hidden behind the Dynamic Memory abstraction.

Comment: @Nguaial: It could allocate from my socks if it wanted to

Comment: Technically `malloc()` can allocate from anywhere it wants so long as the pointer it returns is not used by something else and can contain the amount of data requested. It's not obligated to use the heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general? No.

Not every implementation *has* a heap, or has one used by `malloc()`. And not every local variable is on a "stack". These are hard implementation details.

It may be possible, using the documentation for your specific system, to determine a ruleset to satisfy your goal, but since you are programming in C++ it would be *much* better to not do this at all. Instead, focus on the high-level semantics of your program. Let the compiler and implementation take care of the rest; indeed, that is their job.